# Are Badges on question views overrated?

Tags: discussion, badges, view-badges

I see a lot of people who have little reputation with a lot of gold and silver badges. How? Well, they have asked maybe 300 questions. Sometimes maybe Google references their questions despite them not being very good. They achieved several badges like Famous Question, and it becomes difficult to detect a great question based on the badges.

### Example:

If you take the profile of [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123172/joseph-melettukunnel) (sorry for him, it is just an example), we can deduce that the titles of his questions are so well written that Google must index them very well, whereas the questions don’t have so many votes.

In my humble opinion, titling with *C#, WPF* and a popular control yields lots of views.

Did this deserve 9 silver badges and 20 bronze badges?

### Suggestion

So my suggestion is to give this badges only one time, and not multiple times.

Comment: Why is this so a bad question ?

Comment: On Meta down-votes are a sign of disagreement, it is not necessarily a sign that your question is bad. It is a valid question.

Comment: Note: A low Rep might be the result of a few large bounties on questions.

Comment: badges are overrated in general, imo.

Comment: @Octavian: This is a strange rule I believe. Why the rule differs from the vote rules on questions on stackoverflow? People are used to translate negative votes to words: "this is a dumb question". The disagreement should be expressed in the answer, IMHO.

Comment: @Arsen7 I didn't come up with it. It is just what I have learned and observed.

Comment: I do not blame you! I just have addressed you, because you highlighted that strange rule. Also I hope that some Powerful Ones notice that fact, interfere, and maybe fix the issue unless they designed it this way. ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Regardless, if *lots* of people are finding the question via Google (or web search in general) that means they created a question that was useful to many other people. That is a net positive for the world, and that's why we treat it as a situation worth rewarding and encouraging, e.g. a badge.

There are tons of Stack Overflow questions that are 2+ years old with <= 100 views, for example. It is not a universal truism that every page gets viewed a lot over time.

Random internet users do not randomly end up on web pages en masse* -- there is some bit of information there they were looking for which led them to it. But don't take my word for it, query the data yourself and see:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/103746/old-post-views

for questions more than a year and a half old:

```
<= 100 views     29,356  
>= 1000 views   124,189 
>= 2500 views    48,396  
>= 10000 views    7,298   
all questions   406,417
```

<sub>* except for StumbleUpon, I guess, but I don't understand that service at all. YOU KIDS GET OFF MY LAWN!</sub>

Comment: Nicely explain, and you are right, I see that most of the times, views is related to vote, so...

Comment: @scorp not true, there are plenty of questions that get lots of views but no votes. See http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/103754/questions-with-lots-of-views-but-not-many-votes

Comment: I see this instead http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/103755/

Answer (score 4):

If a question gets that many hits it means that it really is a famous question. Now if you see a question which has that many hits and it is a bad question try to improve it without breaking it.

If the OP failed to make it a good question then it is up to us to make it a good question.

To answer your question. No, no they are not overrated in my opinion.