# Will all questions eventually become popular, notable and famous? Do we have a problem with that?

Tags: discussion, badges, view-badges

I'm no longer active on Stack Overflow, but it seems that any time I land on the site there's a notification that I've earned a badge for a question that has become ["Popular"](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/26/popular-question) or ["Notable"](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/27/notable-question). It seems literally only a matter of time before I "earn" a gold badge for having a ["Famous"](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/28/famous-question) question.  Is there some time limit or other method to prevent questions from accumulating page views for the life of the site?

More importantly, is this a feature or a bug?

On the one hand, when I see the notification that I got a badge just for not deleting my account, I shake my head and think, "Silly system!  Don't you know about the [Poisson law of small numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#The_.22law_of_small_numbers.22)?"

On the other hand, I actually get a little [dopamine rush](http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/brain-bootcamp/200907/techno-addicts) when I think that *my question* was one that other people were interested in reading. I feel like I helped someone who was searching for an answer.

On the third hand, who cares?

Comment: Says the person who has yet to earn the [Tumbleweed](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed) badge... :P

Comment: @iglvzx: [Not so!](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/badges/40/tumbleweed?userid=68)

Comment: Wait... *third hand*? Have you been watching Nationwide commercials?

Comment: Badge inflation, like rep inflation, is not bad.  It's not good.  It just is.  I don't think it's a problem.  The more you contribute, the more badges you get - especially if you contribute valuable stuff, even if it was years ago.

Comment: It's taking a heck of a lot of time with some of mine...

Comment: +1, I just got 'Popular Question' for a question with 0 votes...

Comment: @AndrewBarber It might have been more appropriate to use ["on the gripping hand"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mote_in_God%27s_Eye) here.

Comment: 11 years later, this question has been viewed 322 times.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Will all questions eventually become popular, notable and famous?

[NO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145066/using-typed-data-templates-for-a-single-control).  At least not before the heat death of the universe.  You've clearly asked a lot of really interesting questions that, most importantly, a lot of other people subsequently had.  Your questions were likely worded and titled sufficiently well that Google was able to  lead stumped developers to the right place.  Bottom line: *the system works*

For the rest of us normal folk, we, in the course of learning, ask plenty of simple, boring, often stupid questions that will languish in the depths of Jeff's database rarely to be seen again.

Comment: Flattery will get you... one more page view (and +1 on an question I can't answer).  It seems you are correct about there being questions that are [rarely viewed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95890/1438).

Comment: `"For the rest of us normal folk,..."`, memorable phrase, really beautiful. If we had a database of *The Great Stack Phrases*, I'd vote for this to be included ;)